# Is "At the foundation of ... is ..." correct?

Tags: phrases

In my english test, I wrote this :

> **At the foundation of our society is law**, and taking a look at it might be a good start to get an idea of how much our modern world
>   tends to a perfect equality between men and women.

I was wondering if "At the foundation of ... is ..." was a correct way to say that the law is the foundation of our society.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you wrote is absolutely correct! What you used in your example is called a **delayed subject**, where you put the subject at the end of your sentence or clause, after the verb. Usually you will delay your subject when you want to make it seem **more important**.

[image: From University College London www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/dick/tta/Figs/ss1.gif]

The [University College London has a nice page with a section on subject delay](http://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/dick/tta/sentstruc/sentstruc.htm#delay), and it comes with a few more good examples:

> Lying in the sunshine were two large cats. 
>  At the end of the field stands a stately oak tree. 
>  At last I found the entrance. Lying on top of it was a large stone.

Comment: +1.  We can tell that it's the subject, too, because the verb changes form to agree with it: "In your garden **is a large cat**." but "In your garden **are three large cats**."